# MySQLi *IS* there and functional - but not available in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, mysqli

For me, it is strange, and none of the solutions I found here, works for me.

I am accessing a database by using mysqli. mysqli IS installed and available. My PHP script does work if called from the shell via "php -f myscript.php".

But once I try this from within Eclpse (had 2020-03, just installed 2020-6), I will be informed of "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/..."

As a non-pro, I don't have any idea whether Eclipse is using a different config than my shell. Is that so? If yes, how and where can I configure it correctly, so that I am able to use mysqli from within the Eclipse debugger, too? (It plays no role, if I start my script in debugger or with run command: in the IDE, it cannot find any mysqli function.)

Comment: Check (using phpinfo()) which `php.ini` file is being used by your web server PHP, it could be different to the CLI Version

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solely homemade: In "Debug Configurations" - "PHP Executable", I unchecked the "Use system default php.ini configuration" which obviously was a mistake :-(
Thank you for pointing me into the right direction!